# Question getting downvoted, but unable to delete the question, 2 years later

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, downvoted-questions, old-posts

I've started getting downvoted, for some reason, on a 2-3 year old question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430756/why-does-basic-and-related-languages-use-then-rather-than-than-in-conditio

It is 2 years later, and I now agree that the question sucks. However, I can't remove the question because it has answers. While I understand that we want to prevent question askers from nuking things in the general case, is there any recourse for the asker if they're randomly getting downvoted 2 years later?

Comment: Just because a question gets downvoted doesn't automatically mean it has to be closed or deleted right away. (Although in that case it's debatable whether this is actually a programming question or a English language question.)

Comment: @slhck: I agree, but in this case I think the question *should* be deleted right away. It's terrible.

Comment: Then flag it for moderator attention, because it's actually more an English language question than a programming question.

Comment: Asking on Meta really won't achieve much except for when a SO moderator sees this and decides it needs to go. Flagging would be the proper course of action.

Comment: OH NOES 12 POINTS LOST!  Just write the team and ask them to disassociate the question with your account.  Jeez.

Comment: Aaaand, it's gone.

Comment: VOTING TO UNDELETE
!

Comment: I agree that the question was more of English language usage than programming.  Deleted.

Comment: @Won't Please never leave.

Comment: You want to delete a question just because it's getting down-voted? For someone with 45K rep, I think you still don't grasp what this community is supposed to be about.

Comment: In before [Andy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6430780/1228) asks why he just lost 255 rep.

Comment: @Won't: I don't care about rep here, I care about leaving crappy questions on the site. If I thought the question was good I'd leave it there, despite downvotes.

Comment: @BillyONeal don't feed the trolls

Comment: It is about the English language but it also applies to understanding programming languages for non English speakers. As such it wasn't a totally bad question and it didn't really deserve the downvotes.